# Is there a solution (root) to $(1-x)^{-2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics

I have (via Pollaczek-Khintchine formula):
$$N=\frac{U}{1-U}$$
Now, when I plot this I can see points of inflection, but I want to show where these are algebraically.
But is there a solution to $\frac{1}{(1-U)^2}$ or have I made some mistake along the way here? ($U < 1$ as per the equilibrium condition.)

Comment: What is N? What is U? edit: it seems like the Pollaczek-Khintchine formula relates to probability theory. Why would it apply here?

Comment: Does that matter? I want the point where $\frac{dN}{dU}=0$

Comment: It is an application of probability theory to queues

Comment: I think your plot is incorrect, this function does not have inflection points, $N'(U)>0$ for all $U\neq 1$ and it is undefined at $U=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ is zero if and only if $a=0$ while $b\neq 0$. You have a fraction $\frac{1}{(1-U)^2}$, which can never satisfy the above conditions, thus it is nonzero for every $U$. No root exists.